# Removing the width changes the SVG image top position, why?

Tags: html, css, svg, styles

In this example the SVG image should be at the top of the page. However it is much lower.

Removing the width (in the img style) allows the image to move to the top position correctly.

Is it because of the SVG width & height size being different?
I'm confused, as all the other SVGs on the same page show up correctly positioned. Only the first image is moved down on each page.

You can see an example in the code below here: http://jsfiddle.net/no1uknow/62ATG/

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="page_container">
    <div id='' class='chartdiv' style='page-break-after:always; border:0px solid #000;'>
        <img style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; display: list-item; width: 700px; position: absolute; top: auto; left: auto; height: 1220px; " src="http://dataprofiles.com/20130924.161531.418239-23-0-chartFreqAtaTailNum.svg"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your dimensions (700px by 1220px) is quite the right aspect ratio for the svg.  If you change the CSS slightly:

```
 min-width: 700px;
 max-height: 1220px;
```

The image goes to the top of the page. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/62ATG/1/

Comment: Thank jbaum012, as I told Chris above I also found a solution with surrounding the image with div tags and moving the styles to the div. However I like your solution the best and will use it, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The image itself hasn't moved away from the top of the screen, it's the generated image that has a bunch of white-space at the top of it, and is a result of the image generation.

Perhaps trying out different style parameters until you get the generated image the way you need it without all the unnecessarily-generated white-space would be the way to go? I tried changing the width to `900px` and the image has a lot less white-space generated with it...

Comment: No I think the image has no white-space in it... See the direct link to the image: http://dataprofiles.com/20130924.161531.418239-23-0-chartFreqAtaTailNum.svg

Comment: I updated your fiddle ([check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/62ATG/3/)) and added a border to the generated image so you can see what I mean. The generated image is feeding off your inline styling and creating an image that will fit within your dimensions but still look to scale. This make sense? Play around with the width and see what happens ;)

Comment: Thanks Chris, Understood for some reason the CSS is causing this illusion. The actual image does not appear to have white-space. I thought that is what you were talking about... jbaum012 found a solution below with min-width and max-height. I also found a solution by surrounding the image with div tags and moving the style tag to the div gives the same result as jbaum012... I appreciate your time thank you...